# Object of type JSON non serializable django REST Framwork

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Hi guys I am having the error Object of type 'MyUser' is not JSON serializable, I checke on many post that has the same issue but nothing seems to make my code work

Could someone help me please ?

in my views:

```
class TeamChartData(APIView):
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyUserSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    http_method_names = ['get',]


    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.serializer_class


    def get(self, request, format=None, *args, **kwargs):
        chunk_team = get_chunk_team(self)
        data = {
            "chunk_team":chunk_team
        }
        return Response(data)

def get_chunk_team(self, format=None, *args, **kwargs):
    current_team_member = Project.objects.get(id = self.kwargs['pk']).team_id.members.all()
    print(current_team_member)

    return current_team_member
```

serializer.py :

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers

from registration.models import MyUser
from website.models import Team,Project
from survey.models import Response

class MyUserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    team = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = (
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'team',
        )
    def get_team(self, obj):
        #print(obj) # for you to understand what's happening
        teams = Team.objects.filter(members=obj)
        serialized_teams = TeamSerializer(teams,many=True)
        return serialized_teams.data


class TeamSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = (
            'team_name',
            'team_hr_admin',
            'members',
)
```

I added my log in order for you to have a look on what is going on behing the scenes 
log:

```
<QuerySet [<MyUser: rise1@gmail.com>, <MyUser: rise2@gmail.com>, <MyUser: rise3@gmail.com>]>
Internal Server Error: /website/project/2/api/chart/data2/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", li
ne 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 21
7, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 21
5, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 107
, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 72,
in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 706
, in render
    context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
  File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 664
, in get_context
    'content': self.get_content(renderer, data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context),
  File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 411
, in get_content
    content = renderer.render(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
  File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 105
, in render
    separators=separators
  File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 430, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 404, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 428, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 325, in _iterencode_list
    yield from chunks
  File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 437, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/encoders.py", lin
e 70, in default
    return super(JSONEncoder, self).default(obj)
  File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'MyUser' is not JSON serializable
[21/Dec/2017 14:49:11] "GET /website/project/2/api/chart/data2/ HTTP/1.1" 500 158505
```

Comment: Can you show your log

Comment: see my edited post

Answer (score 0):

The Corresponding view would be as follows:

```
class TeamChartData(APIView):
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyUserSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    http_method_names = ['get',]


    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.serializer_class


    def get(self, request, format=None, *args, **kwargs):
        chunk_team = get_chunk_team(self)
        chunk_team = MyUserSerializer(chunk_team).data #included line
        data = {
            "chunk_team":chunk_team
        }
        return Response(data)

def get_chunk_team(self, format=None, *args, **kwargs):
    current_team_member = Project.objects.get(id = self.kwargs['pk']).team_id.members.all()
    print(current_team_member)

    return current_team_member
```